# Bootstrap submenu caret not visible on iPad 3

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap V3 with a navbar and when I view it on a normal PC I see the caret for the dropdownmenu. When i view the same menu on my iPad 3 I don't see the caret. When I zoom in a little bit the caret become visible. When I zoom out again the caret disappears.

I can also reproduce it with the default navbar example page on getbootstrap. So it seems to be a global issue but Google can't give me answers.

Url: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

On PC it renders the caret always. On the iPad 3 it only renders the caret when zoomed in a little bit.

Edit: Sometimes the carets are directly visible but disappears when changing the iPad from portrait to landscape.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Bootstrap CSS it says `border-top: 4px dashed;` This seems to solve a problem with FireFox (see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17644). When I change it to `border-top: 4px solid;` it solves the problem for me.

Comment: your solution fixed my problem for iOS. Thanks!